# How do I make floating text that fades after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, css-animations

I tried using these codes to make my floating text animation.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.mainButton');
const popUpContainer = document.getElementById('popUpContainer');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const popUpText = document.createElement('span');
  popUpText.textContent = '1+';
  popUpText.classList.add('popUpText');
  const x = event.clientX - popUpContainer.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const y = event.clientY - popUpContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top - 50;
  popUpText.style.left = `${x}px`;
  popUpText.style.top = `${y}px`;

  popUpContainer.appendChild(popUpText);

  setTimeout(function() {
    popUpText.remove();
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.popUpContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popUpText {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: popUpAnimation 2s linear;
  top: 50px;
}

@keyframes popUpAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="popUpContainer"></div>
<button class="mainButton">click me</button>
```

To be more specific, I want to make an animation beside the button that appears and floats upward after clicking a button, like an effect after clicking a button. But after it floats for 2 seconds upward it stops and fades away. I tried using the code provided on top.

I may be stupid by not having something that is crucial to one (or all) of the codes. And I apologize for any unintelligent actions made.

Side note: The HTML part is short I know, there is more to that and just ask if needed.

Comment: If you make a runnable snippet which shows the problem that helps us help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd change `.popUpText` color to `black`, because right now it's white, and it's hard to see it.
2. change `` popUpText.style.top = `${y}px`; `` to `` popUpText.style.top = `${-y}px`; `` because right now the text appears somewhere above the button and isn't visible if the button is close to the top of the window.